# How to simplify a quotient which has the difference of squares in the numerator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify this expression?
$$\frac{10x^2-0.1a^2}{x-0.1a}$$

I tried to expand the expression
$$\frac{10(x^2-0.01a^2)}{x-0.1a}$$ but don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Please use the correct tags.  This is not about regular expressions.

Comment: hint: $0.1 = \frac{1}{10}$ and $0.01=\frac{1}{100}$. Sometimes converting decimals to fractions makes expressions easier to read (and analyse).

Answer (score 4):

HINT : 
$$A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B)$$
with $0.01=0.1\times 0.1.$

Comment: Thanks I worked it out from there.

Comment: @SejadDulic: You are welcome.